# Infinite sum of a modified Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: summation, bessel-functions

I am trying to get that the following sum of a modified Bessel function of the first kind reduces like such:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k I_k(z)=\dfrac{z}{2}(I_0(z)+I_1(z))$$
but I cannot find this equation anywhere in this [Wolfram page](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselI/23/01/). I do not think that I have the wrong expression but am not sure even that this sum should converge.

Comment: It seems to me that $\sum_{k=-n}^n k I_k(z)=0$

Comment: Hi, I thought because $I_{-k}(z)=(-1)^k I_k(z)$, we would have $\sum_{k=-n}^n kI_{k}(z)=\sum_{k=-1}^{-n}k I_k(z)+\sum_{k=1}^nI_k(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n kI_k(z)-(-1)^kkI_k(z)=2\sum_{k=1}^{n \text{ odd}}kI_k(z)$

Comment: @user519208 : In case of $k$ integer , $I_{-k}(z)=I_{k}(z)$ , not the false equation you used. More generally with $\nu$ real $I_{-\nu}(z)=I_{\nu}(z)+\frac{2}{\pi}\sin(\pi\nu)K_\nu(z)$.

Comment: @JJacquelin It seems as though I made a mistake. Thank you for pointing that out. I still need to be able to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k I_k(z)$ and have edited the question.

Comment: @user519208 : A $z$ is missing in your equation. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT :

Starting from the next relationship that one can found in all handbooks of special functions :
$$I_{\nu+1}(z)=I_{\nu-1}(z)-\frac{2\nu}{z}I_{\nu}(z)$$
$$\nu I_{\nu}(z)=\frac{z}{2}\left(I_{\nu-1}(z)-I_{\nu+1}(z)\right)$$
With integer index $\nu=k$ :
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k I_{k}(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z}{2}\left(I_{k-1}(z)-I_{k+1}(z)\right)$$
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k I_{k}(z)=\frac{z}{2}\left( (I_0-I_2)+ (I_1-I_3)+(I_2-I_4)+(I_3-I_5)+ ...  \right)$

After simplification of couples terms which annihilate :

$$\sum_{k=1}^N k I_{k}(z)=\frac{z}{2}\left( I_0(z)+I_1(z)\right)-\frac{z}{2}\left( I_N(z)+I_{N+1}(z)\right)$$

In case of convergence of the series for $N\to\infty$ :
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k I_{\nu}(z)=\frac{z}{2}\left( I_0(z)+I_1(z)\right)$$

This isn't always the case. In case of $z=x$ real large, the asymptotic is :
$$\frac{x}{2}\left( I_N(x)+I_{N+1}(x)\right)\:\sim\: \sqrt{\frac{x}{2\pi}}e^x$$
which doesn't tends to $0$.

In case of $z=x$ real small $\quad \frac{x}{2}\left( I_N(x)+I_{N+1}(x)\right)\:\sim\: \frac{x^{N+1}}{2^{N+1}N!}\quad$ tends to $0$ when $N\to\infty$.